Asynchronous OTel Golang Histograms?
In an eBPF program I'm collecting information about certain Linux kernel tracepoint events into a map-based histogram. As these are high-count tracepoints it most probably doesn't make sense to do the histogram calculations in user space as this would require sending large numbers of events from kernel to user space.
After reading the OTel documentation, and https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/api/#asynchronous-instrument-api and https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/metrics/api/#histogram: does OTel's histogram lack the async version?
If so, how can I do exporting histogram data, where the data comes from an eBPF map and thus isn't collected in user space?
